# Dynamic UI Composition with Angular

Tags: angular

I came from Aurelia framework world, and I am working with Angular now.

At this moment I would like to know how can I do some dynamic ui composition in angular easily.

In aurelia I can do something like that:

index.html

```html
<template>
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
        <div class="row">
            <compose view="./index.desktop.html"></compose>
            <compose view="./index.mobile.html"></compose>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Aurelia will get the html content from both files and will inject into the index.html, and in those files, I can use the property names from the index.ts class to bind inputs or print data.

Essentially is the same that if I copy the content from both files and place in respective compose tags, I used that to have my html in separated files.

How can I do this in angular without creating a component?

Comment: I assume there is no easy way to achieve like that. On the other hand if you use <compose>......</compose>, then why not <somecomponent></somecomponent> where you can create the component with just one command through angular-cli?

Comment: @Manzurul because I dont want the whole workflow of the component to run in my code, I want just to organize the html of a component in other files

Comment: @Manzurul Imagine that I have a page that contains a tabs component, I want to have each tabitem html in separeted file, but it is not a new component

Comment: I believe based on your case this repo can help you https://github.com/lacolaco/ng-dynamic

Comment: @Manzurul I will look this, thanks